# Importing .py files in VS2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, module, python-import

I'm building a python project in VS2015. This project has several files in different folders.For example file `settings.py` in folder `config`. I have a `main.py` file in folder `bin`. In `main.py` I need to import `settings.py`. This is what I'm doing in `main.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import os

print(os.getcwd())  #check if the working directory is right
from config.settings import *
```

However, when I **run** the project, I get this Error:`No module named 'config'`. But if I enter `from config.settings import *` **in the interactive window**, there is no Error comes out. I'm sure folder `config` is under `print(os.getcwd())`. Why this happened? How can I solve it?

Edit:Here is my project structure:
[image]

Comment: We will have to see the directory structure itself, including `__init__.py` files

Comment: Hi @OferSadan. I added it in my post.

Comment: The answer I wrote before was wrong, sorry, so i deleted it. look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: anyway if you want to import `config.settings` in your `main.py` than `config` folder must also be inside `bin` folder